# LinkedIn API failed to connect when trying to get companies informations

Tags: c#, linkedin-api

When I try to get profile information, using `HttpWebRequest`, it works perfectly, it returns the response I need.

But when I try to get company informations, the LinkedIn web service returns the following error.

> { "errorCode": 0,
>       "message": "Unknown authentication scheme", 
>       "requestId": [RequestID],
>       "status": 401,
>       "timestamp": 1479383163405 }

I used the same access token in both queries. And I can't figure why I have a failed authentication in the second query.

There are the 2 functions :

//Get profile :

```
private void GetPeopleProfile(string accessToken) {
    var peopleUrl = String.Format("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~?oauth2_access_token={0}&format=json",accessToken);
    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(peopleUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    JObject updates = JObject.Parse(responseData);

    responseReader.Close();
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();

}
```

//Get profile's Company :

```
private void GetUserCompanies(string accessToken){

    var copaniesUrl = String.Format("https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true?oauth2_access_token={0}&format=json", accessToken);    

    HttpWebRequest webRequest = WebRequest.Create(copaniesUrl) as HttpWebRequest;

    StreamReader responseReader = new StreamReader(webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
    string responseData = responseReader.ReadToEnd();
    JObject updates = JObject.Parse(responseData);

    responseReader.Close();
    webRequest.GetResponse().Close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe wrong URL?

Parameters separators are wrong here (two ? in a URL seems wrong, you are also repeating format=json) :

```
"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true?oauth2_access_token={0}&format=json"
```

This looks better:

```
"https://api.linkedin.com/v1/companies?format=json&is-company-admin=true&oauth2_access_token={0}"
```

You can try the REST api [here](https://apigee.com/console/linkedin) without your code noise.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the Linkedin API now expects an authorization HTTP header instead of a querystring parameter `oauth2_access_token`.

> This is accomplished by including an "Authorization" header in your HTTP call to LinkedIn's API. 
>   https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Try this and remove the access token from the querystring:

```
webRequest Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
```

Comment: Nay, just bad URL format. Linkedin ask for Auth instead of "Invalid company query request" because WebRequest stops URL parsing just before the second "?" so oauth2_access_token is not sended.

Comment: Yes, I saw the double `?` in his URL... I didn't notice it initially.